# whats the better way to implement "paging" for several views? iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, pagination

I am trying to implement a viewcontroller which has in it a list of views where you can scroll horizontally from one to another.

First I tried to implement by using a scroll view with the total width of the views. (but if the views are 30 per example, the result its not good... (30 x 320) not mentioning I would had to add all the content of the views (buttons, subviews, etc))

Then I was thinking about using an UIPageViewController and make my views, a view controller that repeats it self but changes the content.

Can anyone help me by telling what's the best option that I have?

Thank you and best regards,

João Garcia.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is actually with a `UIScrollView` with the `paging` property set to `YES`. Look at [this tutorial](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/) to get started.

Hope you get it working soon!

Comment: yes I have a similar project like this one. But my main issue is the loading of all the information. Because I am making a page composed by a title, subtitle and a video. And there can be like 30 pages. So if I do it like this, I probably will load all the content at once or not?

Comment: I suppose so. I think it's possible to add new views dynamically by changing the properties of the scrollview and adding the viewcontroller you want to display, but i'm not sure. I suppose you could try it out and let us know what happens?